# Оптимальный способ вёрстки Grid-style bottom sheet with header

Tags: android, xml, android-sdk

`GridLayout` является довольно удобным способом для вёрстки `Grid-style bottom sheet with header` (см. ниже). Проблемой является разделитель: если мы зададим `padding` или `margin` для родительского контейнера, разделитель будет начинатсья и заканчиваться в этих пределах, а не как на картинке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал верстать через `TableLayout`. С разделителем проблему решил, указав отступы не для `TableLayout`, а для `TableRow`. Возникло ещё две проблемы:

- Как сделать колонки одинаковой длины (решения, приведённые в ответе на этот [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647177/set-equal-width-of-columns-in-table-layout-in-android), не помогли).
- Если в последней строке неполное количество элементов, то как сделать так, чтобы он занимал только одну ячейку (в `gridLayout` такой проблемы нет).

Итак, вопрос текущей темы: каков оптимальный способ вёрстки `Grid-style bottom sheet with header`? Под оптимальным понимается отображение в соответствии с представленными выше картинками, при этом достигнутое в минимальное количество тэгов и атрибутов.

(Изображения взяты из [официальных гайдлайнов](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-sheets.html#bottom-sheets-specs))