# Android: можно ли провести разделитель, проигнорировав padding контейнера?

Tags: android, xml, android-sdk

Ввиду отсутствия ответов на вопрос [оптимальный способ вёрстки Grid-style bottom sheet with header](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/673646/android-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D0%B2%D1%91%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-grid-style-bottom-sheet-with-header) я решил его конкретизировать. Попробовав верстать приведённый ниже макет (взят с [официальных гайдлайнов](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-sheets.html)), я выяснил, что `GridLayout` всё-таки лучше.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если мы зададим `padding` слева и справа `24dp` контейнеру `GridLayout`, то разделитель строк будет начинаться и заканчиваться в пределах этих отступов. Нужно же чтобы он был от левого до правого края экрана. Как этого можно достичь?

Примерная разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GirdLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingStart="24dp"
    android:paddingEnd="24dp"
    >

    <!-- Содержимое -->

    <View 
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_color="#000"
        android:alpha="0.14"
        />

</GirdLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно. Нужно установить у контейнера `android:clipToPadding="false"`, а у разделителя поставить отрицательный `margin`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GirdLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingStart="24dp"
    android:paddingEnd="24dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    >

    <!-- Содержимое -->

    <View 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="-24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-24dp"
        android:alpha="0.14"
        android:background="#000"
        />

</GirdLayout>
```

Comment: Всё прекрасно сверстал! Благодарю Вас за ответ!